# other than system admins no one should not have access to choose the closed date less than today's date

Tags: validation

I just joined the Salesforce Stack Exachange. Iam very much intrested in learning Salesforce and just entered into the world of Salesforce. I have a doubt in validation Rules.
Can anyone please help me in this. I have created a Validation Rule of Closed Date should not be less than Today's date. [CloseDate  <= TODAY()].
My question is "Only System Admins should have access to choose the Closed Date less than Today's Date??"
Can anyone please help on this? Thankful in advance.

Thanks
Rekha

Comment: Stackexchange is great, but you'll learn even faster if you go to [Salesforce Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/trails) and complete all the Admin trails and modules, and read through all the [Salesforce User Guides](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=getstart_help.htm&type=0)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you please also add one more condition
either
AND
$User.ProfileId != "Admin profile id"
or
The most feasible will be just check the current user's profile in validation rule 
as below,
 AND $Profile.Name != "System Administrator",

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thank you for the quick response. I just tried to implement the one which you said, " CloseDate  <= TODAY()
AND $Profile.Name!="System Administrator", it is showing the error Syntax error Extra AND. Can you please help me

Comment: Please use AND(CloseDate <= TODAY() , $Profile.Name!="System Administrator")

Comment: Please mark it as answer, as it works. So thread will be closed here :)

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try !!

And( $User.ProfileId <> 'typeProfileIdHere' , ISCHANGED( close_dat__c ) , close_dat__c  < Today() )